# Remove reference from object javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am searching a solution where I can replace a object content with other in a array of objects.

The thing is, I don't know what my function will pass, so I can't pass the values inside as keys directly, so the reference won't be copied, is there any way I can assign the value directly without passing the reference? I know that objects pass references and not values, but is there a way to do that?

I tried two ways:

```
state.document["atributes"].splice(state.document["atributes"][state.currentIndex],1,section);
```

And

```
state.document["atributes"][state.currentIndex] = section
```

Where my `state.document["atributs"]` is my array, and the `state.currentIndex` the index where I want to replace the element inside my array.

What happens at the moment is that my object can be a Table a paragraph etc.

If the objects are the same it replaces the content :/

Any help with this? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: your second solution should be allright enough, but instead of assigning the object as a value, you should assign a deep copy of it (see other comments links on how to make a deep copy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only modify what in the currentIndex, try

```
Vue.set(state.document["atributes"], state.currentIndex, section)
```

Reference: [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)